# R: using 'funs' within a `summarise_each` to generate a confidence interval:

Tags: r, functional-programming, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse) # library(dplyr) # would probably work, too.
```

Given a data frame:

```
my_df <- data.frame(run = c(1,2,3,4),
                w_t = c(5.452595, 4.719883, 5.110823, 5.009686),
                L = c(4.212980, 4.674020, 3.849464, 3.971810), 
                mu = c(0.9962918, 1.0141293, 0.9962637, 0.9954),
                n = c(4,4,4,4))
```

Note that this is a small subset of the actual data set (many more columns are not shown).  I'd like to generate a number of stats and I use `dplyr` to do so:

```
my_stats <- my_df %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(w_t, L, mu) %>%  
  summarise_each(funs(mean, sd, min, max))
```

This works and results in a df with 12 columns with naming format: colname_stat.

**My question**:  Is there a way to insert a function into the `summarise_each` such that the result *also* contains the 95% confidence interval?  I.e. it'd look something like:  `summarise_each(funs(mean, sd, min, max, blah))` where `blah` would be a function that's called or an equation that I put in.  It could be two parts such that I need to enter one equation for lower and one for upper, etc.

I've created a function to get me a half-width confidence interval, but I haven't figured out how to make it work inside the `funs` of the statement.  It looks like this:

```
my_ct <- function(s, n, ci){
  # you must enter the ci in decimal e.g. .95
  z_t <- qt( 1-(1-ci)/2, df = n-1)
  h <- z_t * s/sqrt(n)
  return(h)
}
```

I'm arranging the data in this manner for comparison and a data frame provides a flexible format for me to present.

Comment: You'll want to use `summarise_all` instead, by the way. `summarise_each` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? No need to pass `n` or `s`, you can just calculate that within your function:

```
get_CI_half_width <- function(x, prob) {
  n <- length(x)
  z_t <- qt(1 - (1 - prob) / 2, df = n - 1)
  z_t * sd(x) / sqrt(n)
}

lower <- function(x, prob = 0.95) {
  mean(x) - get_CI_half_width(x, prob)
}

upper <- function(x, prob = 0.95) {
  mean(x) + get_CI_half_width(x, prob)
}

my_df %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(w_t, L, mu) %>%  
  summarise_all(funs(mean, sd, min, max, lower, upper))
```

Gives:

> ```
>   w_t_mean   L_mean  mu_mean   w_t_sd      L_sd       mu_sd  w_t_min    L_min mu_min  w_t_max   L_max   mu_max w_t_lower  L_lower
> 1 5.073247 4.177068 1.000521 0.302337 0.3640999 0.009081505 4.719883 3.849464 0.9954 5.452595 4.67402 1.014129  4.592161 3.597704
>    mu_lower w_t_upper  L_upper mu_upper
> 1 0.9860705  5.554332 4.756433 1.014972
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Axeman! This looks good.  I guess the issue with my function (besides the naming convention :) ) was that it needed too many inputs to work with `funs`, right?

Comment: @jmb277, it's inconvenient at least. Functions in `funs` should really just take one variable (and possibly some constants).